# Distribution of Regression Residuals: Is this a normal distribution?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest, matplotlib

I've created a histogram as well as a QQPlot from the residuals of my Regression Model:

Mean: 0.35
Standard Deviation: 18.14

[image: QQPlot]
[image: Histogram]

Judging from these plots, is it okay to say that my residuals are normally distributed?
Or what else can I draw from these plots?

**Update: Created the Histogram using**

```
ns.distplot(x, hist=True)
```

Here's the result:
[image: https://i.imgur.com/xWdchCB.png]

Comment: I think it is fair to say that you residuals are normally distributed.

Comment: thanks for your reply! The outlier in the bottom left corner worries me a little, what can be the reason for this?

Comment: I added a new Histogram that I created using: ns.distplot(x, hist=True)

Comment: The outlier (one I guess) is really in the left tail of the distribution. I don‘t know what you are up to, but I think it is still save to claim that the errors are well approximated by a normal distribution.

Comment: I see, thanks! The thing that worries me is that the tests for normal distribution don't 'classify' my data as normally distributed. But I've researched a little and found that those tests aren't necessarily useful when it comes to determining whether data is normally distributed. Would you agree with that? (Check, for example the answer from Julio below=

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a statistical test to confirm your data is normally distributed
Try:

```
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.normal(2, 1, size=1000)
k2, p = stats.normaltest(x)
alpha = 0.001
print("p = {:g}".format(p))

if p < alpha:  # null hypothesis: x comes from a normal distribution
    print("The null hypothesis can be rejected")
else:
    print("The null hypothesis cannot be rejected")
```

> This function tests the null hypothesis that a sample comes from a normal distribution. It is based on D’Agostino and Pearson’s test that combines skew and kurtosis to produce an omnibus test of normality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I get the following results:
`p = 3.24783e-17
The null hypothesis can be rejected`

Is it safe to say that the data does not follow a normal distribution even though the plots look like it does?

Comment: I also added the new Histogram created using ns.distplot(x, hist=True)

Comment: @0009 Formal hypothesis for distribution fits it surprisingly unhelpful. See this answer from today: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/502264/247274.

Comment: thank you very much, that is very helpful! This means that I can deduce normal distribution just from my histogram and QQPlot?

Comment: 0009 - What you stated in the last comment is completely out of reason. And Dave's situation is not an argument to establish that you should not use a statistical test since in there, It is only shown a single case in which a single test failed to correctly assess normality, what does not mean any test is useless

Comment: @Julio Jesus Luna - Okay, I'm still learning, sorry. So what can I deduce from the results that I obtained from the test that you suggested?

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to be rude, what I mean is that is nonsense to establish conclusions by visual inspecting over statistical tests. In practice, you will never be "100% sure" of the true distribution of your data, that's why you run tests that allow you with certain level of confidence state something about the true distribution. Of course, every test has its pluses and minuses and the important part lies in knowing them and considering when making decisions based upon them.

Comment: @ Julio Jesus Luna - Don't worry, no offense taken. I understand and maybe I did not express myself well and completely understand that it doesn't make sense to draw a definite conclusion just from looking at a graph. Can you give me any additional tips on which test I can use and what level of confidence I should use for the tests?

Comment: Given it seems your data has outliers, I would go for test robust to this scenario, one option is Kolmogorov Smirnov that since it takes the commutative distribution, it is not prone to fail on the presence of outliers. Check the docs and examples on scipy and you will check that they also mention what Dave also did regarding to the t distribution. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kstest.html

Comment: @JulioJesus - thanks for the suggestion! I've looked into the Kolmogorov Smirnov tests and according to this topic (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903977/implementing-a-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-python-scipy), it is testing against "a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation of 1". Since my data does not have a mean of 0 and a standard dev of 1, would it make sense to standardize my data?

Comment: @JulioJesus - 
Results from kstest before standardizing: `KstestResult(statistic=0.4547082777994218, pvalue=2.5356347682073354e-225)`
Results from kstest after standardizing: 
`KstestResult(statistic=0.04947243820467989, pvalue=0.005701404849410582)`

Comment: Is my interpretation of the results correct when saying that my data is not normally distributed?

Comment: @0009 It is important to understand the considerable limitations of formal hypothesis tests like the method given in this answer, and that is discussed extensively in the link I gave. In particular, rejecting the null hypothesis of normality does not imply a meaningful departure from normality that warrants a change of methodology (nor does it preclude a meaningful departure from normality), and failing to reject the null hypothesis does not confirm normality (the usual business about not accepting null hypotheses).